# How to do getElementsByTagName() using ElementTree?

Tags: python, xml, getelementsbytagname

I've used Python's `miniDom` library before. It had a useful method that I'm missing in the [ElementTree library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) :

> `getElementsByTagName('bar')`
>
> `getElementsByTagName()` finds all children of a given name, no
> matter how deep, thus working recursively. This is usually good, but
> can cause problems if similar nodes exist at multiple levels and the
> intervening nodes are important.

source: http://wiki.python.org/moin/MiniDom

Does such a function also exist in `ElementTree`? I've looked through the docs, but couldn't find it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

ElementTree uses an XPath subset for selecting nodes within the XML tree. You can use `tree.findall( './/bar' )` to find all `bar` nodes within the tree.

Comment: Nice, straight-forward answer.

Comment: Another question related to this problem emerges:
I've got nodes that contain additional parameters like <cookies odt=12 ...>

If I apply list_of_nodes=tree.findall('.//cookies') it gives me lateron, when I want to get the text of a specific node: list_of_nodes[0].text -----> '\n\t\t\t '

additional information: the cookie nodes, contain also further nodes

Comment: `findall` returns a list of `Element` objects. On those you can use the usual methods to traverse deeper if you like, or get attribute values or whatever. So when you want to get a child of `list_of_nodes[0]`, use that object’s `find` method (or `findall` again).